# Javascript, React Ref and Switch (Looking for a better solution)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, switch-statement, ref

I have the following code that uses multiple `useRef()` hooks and a `switch` statement to scroll to a specific `ref` based on an `index` value:

```js
const ref0 = useRef();
const ref1 = useRef();
const ref2 = useRef();
const ref3 = useRef();
const ref4 = useRef();

switch(index) {
  case 0:
    ref0?.current?.scrollIntoView();
    break;
  case 1:
    ref1?.current?.scrollIntoView();
    break;
  case 2:
    ref2?.current?.scrollIntoView();
    break;
  case 3:
    ref3?.current?.scrollIntoView();
    break;
  case 4:
    ref4?.current?.scrollIntoView();
    break;
  default: 
    break;
}
```

How can I improve this code to make it shorter and more efficient?

Comment: put the refs in an array? `const refs = [ref0, ref1...]; refs[index].current?.scrollIntoView();`

Answer (score 1):

You can just use an array of refs like this:

```
import { createRef, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

export default function Sample() {
    // create a ref with its content of 10 refs
    const refs = useRef([]);
    refs.current = Array.from({ length: 10 }).map(() => createRef());

    useEffect(() => {
        // you can call any dom methods here, call inside any of your listeners' callback or effects
        const indexOfRefIWantToScroll = 5;
        refs.current[indexOfRefIWantToScroll].current?.scrollIntoView();
    }, []);

    // bind each ref to your element
    return (<>
        { Array.from({ length: 10 }).map((ele, index) => <div ref={refs.current[index]} key={index} className='scrollElement'></div>) }
    </>)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
const refs = [useRef(), useRef(), useRef(), useRef(), useRef()];

refs.forEach((ref, i) => {
  if (i === index) {
    ref?.current?.scrollIntoView();
  }
});
```

Changed your switch-case to foreach loop. It iterates through array and find the one that meets the condition.

**Update:**

You can simply use refs[index]?.current?.scrollIntoView(), instead of iterating through array. This will be much more performant.

Comment: why would you use a loop and not simply access by index?

Comment: @pilchard you are right, instead of loop, you can simply use
```
ref[index]?.current?.scrollIntoView();
```